# Selecting one Checkbox out of multiple checkboxes & getting user selected Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I have 16 checkboxes in an activity out of which user has to select any 1 out of 8 checkboxes.
 So, ultimately user will be selecting 2 checkboxes out of 16 of them. 
**Update:**The checkboxes are already there in the xml layout file. So, I do have access to their ID's 
Till now, I was thinking to implement a simple onCheckedChange listener and in a switch case block select any 1 checkbox out of 8 checkboxes and deselect the rest 7 of them. But this approach is extremely painful. 
 
Also, when I would need to extract which of them is selected then it would be a complete mess.
 So, what is the simplest yet flexible way I can do both of these things? Suggestions are welcome 
Thanks

Comment: use two groups of `RadioGroup` , each one will contains 8 `radioButtons`

Comment: Radio group is a right option for this scenario. Two groups of radio group with 8 radio buttons each will do the job!

Comment: @Houcine & @Gridtestmail Thanks for replying. I am using checkboxes and would not want to use `RadioGroup`. I know its way simple to use it. But I would like to stick to checkboxes only..for now :D

Comment: then you got to do it seperately unfortunately!

Comment: if you did it with checkboxes , the user can check them all if he wants, and it not what you want :) , you want it to check just one from 8 possibilites

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4492417

Comment: @Luksprog Hey Luksprog, Thanks for the sample but I have already implemented it. Many thanks for helping me out :D Also, can you post it in the answer? Will be happy to mark it & help other fellas out here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep only one `CheckBox` checked at a time(similar to a `RadioGroup`) by grouping them in an array(for easy access and handling) and also setting a `OnClickListener` to each one to set the status:

```
CheckBox[] chkArray = new CheckBox[8];
chkArray[0] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1R1);
chkArray[0].setOnClickListener(mListener);
chkArray[1] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2R1); // what id do you have?
chkArray[1].setOnClickListener(mListener);
// so on for the rest of the 8 CheckBoxes

private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() { 

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        final int checkedId = v.getId();
        for (int i = 0; i < chkArray.length; i++) {
            final CheckBox current = chkArray[i];
            if (current.getId() == checkedId) {
                 current.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                 current.setChecked(false);
            }
       }    
    }
};
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Use *... if (current.getId() == checkedId) {
                 current.setChecked(current.isChecked());
            } ...* .

Comment: Your logic helped me .

Answer (score 0):

just give them simple names like list1box1 list1box2.... list2box1 list2box2...
have two arrays for the names - list1array - list2array

still have your same listener as you do now:
Inside the listener first do an if statement to check if the item clicked is a list1 item or list2 and based on that simply have a for loop that loops through all the items in that specific list and checks/unchecks.

to extracts just check each array which items are checked or not

Comment: Thanks for replying. [Here](http://pastebin.com/qubvPw2s) (PasteBin Link) is my current implementation. Can you please elaborate on my code? I feel that the first `if` you talked about of checking an item for to which `list array` it belongs to can be done **but** the `for` loop which iterates through all the items in a specific list and checks a single box/unchecks all others won't be possible?

Comment: nvm I have an answer. I implemented it in the simplest yet painful way.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Code**
*You can keep only one CheckBox checked at a time(similar to a RadioGroup) by grouping them in an array(for easy access and handling) and also setting a OnClickListener to each one to set the status:*
*And getting value only English language*

```
 private var ug:String? = null
private var pg:String? = null
private var g:String? = null
private var chkArrayQualification = arrayOfNulls<CheckBox>(3)

chkArrayQualification[0] = binding.cbUnGraduate
    ug = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_ug,"en")
    chkArrayQualification[0]?.setOnClickListener(clickListenerQual)
    chkArrayQualification[1] = binding.cbGraduate
    g = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_graduate,"en")
    chkArrayQualification[1]?.setOnClickListener(clickListenerQual)
    chkArrayQualification[2] = binding.cbPstGraduate
    pg = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_pg,"en")
    chkArrayQualification[2]?.setOnClickListener(clickListenerQual)
```

*click listener method call*

```
private val clickListenerQual: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
    val checkedId: Int = view.id
    for (i in chkArrayQualification.indices) {
        val current = chkArrayQualification[i]
        if (current?.id == checkedId) {
            val checkBoxQualifierInfo = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(current.id)
            var cbValueQualification = checkBoxQualifierInfo.text.toString()
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.cb_un_graduate -> {
                    cbValueQualification = ug!!
                    Log.i("TAG", "Qualification: $cbValueQualification")
                }
                R.id.cb_graduate -> {
                    cbValueQualification = g!!
                    Log.i("TAG", "Qualification: $cbValueQualification")
                }
                R.id.cb_pst_graduate -> {
                    cbValueQualification = pg!!
                    Log.i("TAG", "Qualification: $cbValueQualification")
                }
            }
            current?.isChecked = true
        } else {
            current?.isChecked = false
        }
    }
}
```

*checked checkbox and getting value only English language*

```
fun getResStringLanguage(id: Int, lang: String?): String? {
    val res = resources
    val conf = res.configuration
    val savedLocale = conf.locale
    val confAr = resources.configuration
    confAr.locale = Locale(lang)
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    val resources = Resources(resources.assets, metrics, confAr)
    val string = resources.getString(id)
    conf.locale = savedLocale
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null)
    return string
}
```